# How to use Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I would like to know how can I start a crawler based on Scrapy. I installed the tool via apt-get install and I tried to run an example:

```
/usr/share/doc/scrapy/examples/googledir/googledir$ scrapy list
directory.google.com

/usr/share/doc/scrapy/examples/googledir/googledir$ scrapy crawl
```

I hacked the code from spiders/google_directory.py but it seems that it is not executed, because I don't see any prints that I inserted. I read their documentation, but I found nothing related to this; do you have any ideas?

Also, if you think that for crawling a website I should use other tools, please let me know. I'm not experienced with Python tools and Python is a must.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the spider name in the crawl command. Use:

```
$ scrapy crawl directory.google.com
```

Also, I suggest you copy the example project to your home, instead of working in the `/usr/share/doc/scrapy/examples/` directory, so you can modify it and play with it:

```
$ cp -r /usr/share/doc/scrapy/examples/googledir ~
$ cd ~/googledir
$ scrapy crawl directory.google.com
```

Answer (score 7):

EveryBlock.com released some [quality scraping code](http://code.google.com/p/ebcode/) using lxml, urllib2 and Django as their stack.

[Scraperwiki.com](http://scraperwiki.com/) is inspirational, full of examples of python scrapers.

Simple example with cssselect:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

dom = fromstring('<html... ...')
navigation_links = [a.get('href') for a in htm.cssselect('#navigation a')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I will take a look on these technologies later.